# Simple addition and subtraction not working correctly

Tags: php, math, addition, subtraction

I've inherited a project written in PHP which has a double entry style cashbook, which requires that the amount going in is equal to the amount going out.

When validating figures entered via a form (to work out if it equals zero), it runs the code below which works fine until there is a decimal number, which seems to make it randomly fall over and return an incorrect value.

In the example below, it returns a really tiny number from 53.87 - 53.87, which should be zero.This has been stripped back to eliminate other things from causing problems, so I've removed a lot of input validation etc.

```
<?php $inputs = array(
    array(
        "in" => '',
        "out" => '249.6',
    ),
    array(
        "in" => '',
        "out" => '396',
    ),
    array(
        "in" => '554.4',
        "out" => ''
    ),
    array(
        "in" => '145.07',
        "out" => ''
    ),
    array(
        "in" => '',
        "out" => '53.87',
    ),
);
$fTotal = 0;
echo "Start at 0:   ";
foreach($inputs as $key=>$sRef) {
    $itemValid = true;
    $aItem = array();
    $amountIn = $inputs[$key]['in'];
    $amountOut = $inputs[$key]['out'];
    if ($itemValid) {
        echo "'".$fTotal."'";
        $is_in = 0;
        if ($amountIn > 0.0) {
            $is_in = 1;
            echo "+";
            $amount = $amountIn;
            $fTotal = $fTotal + $amountIn;
        } else {
            $is_in = 0;
            echo "-";
            $amount = $amountOut;
            $fTotal = $fTotal - $amountOut;
        }
        echo "'".$amount."'=";
        echo "'".$fTotal."'   |   ";
        $aItem["is_in"] = $is_in;
        $aItem["amount"] = $amount;
        $aItems[] = $aItem;
    }
 }
```

You can run this on a sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5882952ff94178eb420cb4e795247e748c61d41a).

Here is the expected output:

> Start at 0:   '0'-'249.6'='-249.6'   |   '-249.6'-'396'='-645.6'   |   '-645.6'+'554.4'='-91.2'   |   '-91.2'+'145.07'='53.87'   |   '53.87'-'53.87'='0'   |

Here is the actual output:

> Start at 0:   '0'-'249.6'='-249.6'   |   '-249.6'-'396'='-645.6'   |   '-645.6'+'554.4'='-91.2'   |   '-91.2'+'145.07'='53.87'   |   '53.87'-'53.87'='-4.9737991503207E-14'   |

What is wrong here?

**Update**

Following help below, [here's the working code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c0ee8eb05cf456e7da985071b403c9bca88c4e1) for anyone who stumbles on this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of floating point (decimal) maths where computers like binary maths. Sometimes decimal numbers don't have a nice representation in binary so these tiny differences happen.

If you can state that every number can be rounded to 2 decimal points, and based on your limited dataset, wrapping your 'sums' in `number_format($fTotal + $amountIn , 2)` etc can sort this out for you.

Alternatively for a "more accurate", just wrap the final one eg. `echo "'".number_format($fTotal, 2)."'   |   ";` (or 0 or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers are being interpreted as strings.

Try this:

```
<?php
$inputs = array(
    array(
        "in" => 0,
        "out" => 249.6,
    ),
    array(
        "in" => 0,
        "out" => 396,
    ),
    array(
        "in" => 554.4,
        "out" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "in" => 145.07,
        "out" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "in" => 0,
        "out" => 53.87,
    ),
);

$fTotal = 0;

echo "Start at 0:   ";
foreach($inputs as $key => $sRef) {
    $itemValid = true;

    $amountIn = $sRef['in'];
    $amountOut = $sRef['out'];

    if ($itemValid) {

        echo $fTotal;

        $is_in = 0;
        if ($amountIn > 0.0) {

            $is_in = 1;

            echo "+";

            $amount = floatval($amountIn);
            $fTotal = floatval($fTotal) + floatval($amountIn);

        } else {

            $is_in = 0;

            echo "-";

            $amount = floatval($amountOut);
            $fTotal = floatval($fTotal) - floatval($amountIn);

        }

        echo $amount;
        echo ' = ' . $fTotal . "  |  ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bcsub() function in PHP is an inbuilt function and is used to subtract one arbitrary precision number from another.

Syntax:
`string bcsub ( $num_str1, $num_str2, $scaleVal)`

Example :
`<?php $num_str1 = "8"; $num_str2 = "3";` $res = bcsub($num_str1, $num_str2)   `echo $res; ?>`
Result:

5